# What do you call 'underground floors' in AmE and BrE?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, british-english

I understand that the word [basement](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/basement) means:

> the part of a building that is wholly or partly below ground level

[Merriam-Webster]

But I wonder what American English and British English call 'the first basement floor right below the first floor of a building' and 'the second basement floor beneath the first basement floor'.

Is it all right to call it 'basement one' and 'basement two' in both AmE and BrE?

---

The most common English translation for what the Chinese call this type of floor is *underground floor*, or *first/second/third/etc. floor underground*, as evidenced by this link: http://eng.ichacha.net/underground%20floor.html

Is this terminology also acceptable in colloquial AmE and BrE, or is it more technical in nature?

Comment: I don't believe there is a single universal term, but in the US I've often heard "sub-basement" and even "sub-sub-basement" used for floors -2 and below.  Probably "the basement", "the first sub-basement", and "the second sub-basement" would be well-understood and not too awkward.  The other option, if you need to do this a lot, is to establish a notation of -1 for the basement and -2, -3... for sub-basements.  (Though that gets confusing since sometimes zero is used for the basement.)

Comment: The OP has given his "best guesses," thereby demonstrating "research" undertaken over two days. He's asking about multiple versions of a word in two "dialects" (American and British English,) What more can you close voters reasonably want? That he looks up every "permutation when more knowledgeable people have an answer at their fingertips?

Comment: This question was maliciously edited into utter nonsense.  I just now rolled it back.

Comment: In the UK, I've seen 'Basement Level 1'; 'Basement Level 2'; etc..  OP really needs to clarify which country (US or UK or elsewhere) he is concerned with - because the UK & US count floor numbers differently from one another.

Comment: @HotLicks If 'zero' were used at all, in the UK it would refer to 'Ground Floor' (usually indicated by "G"): your first & second floors are our ground & first floors, respectively.

Comment: @TomAu The OP should give us a link and its contents to show us his research efforts. Giving his "best guesses" doesn't count as research. BTW, how do you know the OP undertook research over two days? What is wrong with putting this question on hold until the OP clears the question and include some research. Will it harm ELU? What is your thought?

Comment: @Rathony: I believe in giving people the benefit of the doubt, but others may reasonably disagree.

Comment: @TomAu I will be more than happy to give some people the benefit of the doubt as long as they show a little bit of research effort. There is none.  Please read the comment below I left to ab2.

Comment: @Lee You should be aware that the edit you made is vandalism which is not tolerated on ELU. Don't do it again.

Comment: @TrevorD It is not just the UK where the floor at ground level is "floor 0" or "Ground Floor", and the one above is the "first floor". That logic applies throughout Europe, and I believe much of the world outside America. But I have seen "basement" and "sub-basement" and also Bi, B2 etc.

Comment: @WS2 I didn't mean to - and don't believe that I did - imply that it is **only** the UK.  I specifically said that Op needs to "clarify which country (US or UK or _elsewhere_) he is concerned with" and that "the _UK & US_ count floor numbers differently".  I _purposely did not_ mention any other specific countries (e.g. other European countries, or Canada) because I don't know enough about them to comment in this respect.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to a "proper" expression for underground floors is that there is no standardized nomenclature, rather, there are multiple different designators depending on the place in question and the country: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storey#Subterranean_floors

> The numbering of levels below ground is also quite varied, even within the same country. In English-speaking countries, the first level below ground may be labelled **B for "Basement"**, **LL for "Lower Level" or "Lower Lobby"**, **C for "Cellar"** or, in the case of the Andy Warhol Museum in Pittsburgh, **U for "Underground"**. In British buildings, **LG for "Lower Ground"** is commonly encountered (or [lower ground floor](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/lower-ground-floor)).
>
> If there is more than one basement, the next level down may be marked **SB for "Sub-Basement"**. The lower levels may also be numbered B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B9, B10, etc.. Negative numbers are sometimes used: −1 for the first level below ground, −2 for the second one, −3, −4, −5, −6, −7, −8, −9, −10, etc. Lettered levels are also sometimes used: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, etc.
>
> In Hawaiian, these levels are numbered I1, I2, I3, and so on. The "I" stands for "Ilelo", meaning basement.

Of course, that's not to say that people won't understand you if you use *first floor underground*, but I think the reason this isn't widely used is because it's just a mouthful. Five syllables, versus the three syllables of **basement 1**, or **first basement**.

---

*First floor underground* has been used, though, and can be found in various engineering books, particularly in the English translation of Chinese manuals:

[Code for Fire Protection Design of Buildings](https://books.google.com/books?id=e5zICgAAQBAJ&pg=PA49&dq=%22first+floor+underground%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5v8PhuvjNAhUE4IMKHUUKDRoQ6AEILDAC#v=onepage&q=%22first%20floor%20underground%22&f=false)

> "If they are arranged underground or semi-underground, they should be arranged on the **first floor underground** but shall not be arranged on the third floor underground or below."

[The 2nd International Symposium on Rail Transit Comprehensive Development ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=MC-_BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA276&dq=%22first+floor+underground%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5v8PhuvjNAhUE4IMKHUUKDRoQ6AEIPDAF#v=onepage&q=%22first%20floor%20underground%22&f=false)

> "Commercial space is located on the podium and the **first floor underground**, while the commercial apartment is located in the high-rise building on the north side."

[Advances in Civil Engineering and Building Materials](https://books.google.com/books?id=OyvMBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA949&dq=%22first+floor+underground%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5v8PhuvjNAhUE4IMKHUUKDRoQ6AEIQTAG#v=onepage&q=%22first%20floor%20underground%22&f=false)

> "The **first floor underground** chooses the zoning control combined with the light tube during the day and close corresponding area lights and it is open the evening. The **second floor underground** is also lighting for garage."

[Rainbow Town](https://books.google.com/books?id=8ujfB0VWSlYC&pg=PA81&dq=%22first+floor+underground%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5v8PhuvjNAhUE4IMKHUUKDRoQ6AEIRjAH#v=onepage&q=%22first%20floor%20underground%22&f=false)

> "These two were the ones who said they wanted to stay on the **first floor underground**"

[Civil Engineering in Japan, Volumes 6-8](https://books.google.com/books?id=0k5IAQAAIAAJ&q=%22first+floor+underground%22&dq=%22first+floor+underground%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5v8PhuvjNAhUE4IMKHUUKDRoQ6AEISzAI)

> "View of the illumination towers from the vicinity of the taxi station, the **first floor underground**."

[CCDI Architecture: Interaction with a Complex Context](https://books.google.com/books?id=2L8KOz81Hf0C&pg=PA110&dq=%22first+floor+underground%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5v8PhuvjNAhUE4IMKHUUKDRoQ6AEITzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22first%20floor%20underground%22&f=false)

> " The commercial building comprises the main department stores and retail business, with the supermarket and retail space on the **first floor underground**."

[Re/collecting Early Asian America: Essays in Cultural History](https://books.google.com/books?id=fjeAaEqo-CEC&pg=PA64&dq=%22first+floor+underground%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5v8PhuvjNAhUE4IMKHUUKDRoQ6AEIVDAK#v=onepage&q=%22first%20floor%20underground%22&f=false)

> "The **first floor underground** was the home of the "number two" employees. In the Chinese social code actors belonged in the lower strata."

...and more can be found in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22first+floor+underground%22&oq=%22first+floor+underground%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.12845j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22first+floor+underground%22&tbm=bks&start=10)

---

[Ngrams shows that **basement floor** is the outright winner](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sub-basement%2Csub+basement%2Csubbasement%2Cunderground+floor%2Cfloor+underground%2Cbasement+floor%2Cfloor+basement%2Cbasement+level%2Clower+lobby%2Clower+ground+floor%2Clower+level+floor%2Clower+floor+level&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csub%20-%20basement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csub%20basement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubbasement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunderground%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfloor%20underground%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbasement%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfloor%20basement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbasement%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clower%20lobby%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clower%20ground%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clower%20level%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clower%20floor%20level%3B%2Cc0) compared to **underground floor**/**floor underground**/**basement level**/**floor basement**/**lower ground floor**/**lower lobby**/**lower level floor**/**lower floor level**/**sub-basement**/**subbasement**/**sub basement**. I didn't include *lower level* because the results would be corrupted by the common definition of *level*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a dwelling-house, then I would call the eerie floor under your groundfloor (where the spiders reside) your *cellar*. If you've turned it into a nice, cosy place to sit in at times, it's the *basement*. It's the same with your top floor. The *attic* is where those creepy creatures crawl, but if you keep it neat and tidy you could call it the *loft*.

Comment: Interesting commentary, but the question seems to be focused on the situation where there are *multiple* underground levels.  Also, do you have a reference for the above, or are you just speaking from personal knowledge? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score -1):

The floor below the ground is the basement, the floor below the basement is the sub basement, and the floor below the sub basement is a hypobasement.

Comment: You might want to include some source references to support your answer.

Comment: I have never in my 70 years heard "hypobasement".